# I'm trying to do the two sum and the return values switch and I dont know why

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a sorted array in non-decreasing order I have to pair to integers so that they add to the target value. I go about it with two pointers from the beginnning increasing it when the sum is smaller than the target, and from the end decreasing it when the sum is bigger than the target value. Why do they switch?

```
numbers is a List[int] and target is int
```

```
        l = 0
        r = len(numbers)-1
        while (l < r):
            if numbers[l] + numbers[r] == target:
                return {l+1, r+1}
            elif numbers[l] + numbers[r] > target:
                r -= 1
            elif numbers[l] + numbers[r] < target:
                l += 1
```

The other tests work out fine. A test with more numbers in the array gives the right values, but inversed. As in `{12, 3}` for example.

Comment: No it doesn't. Here I'm using a list and my problem is with these "iterators" not with the list itself

Comment: `{l+1, r+1}` is a set, so the iteration order (including the order when you print) is indeterminate. For a list, `return [l+1, r+1]` instead. Or you could do simply `return l+1, r+1` which returns a tuple - that also guarantees the iteration order.